# Yii model update form textfield displayes html encoded value

Tags: yii

I am using the following code in my model form view.

```
echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>200));
```

I have 'services & package' as value for the name field.When i take the update form, the value in the textfield displays as 'services & amp; packages'. 
Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable automatic html encoding by `encode` html option like below:

```
echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>200,'encode'=>FALSE));
```